# Access to localhost on Mac OS Sonoma 14.1.2 (23B92) from Parallels 19.1.0 (54729) Windows 11

Tags: localhost, parallels

Installed local MAMP server on Mac Os

```
You have new mail.
mykhailo_bodnar@Mihajlos-MacBook-Air ~ % ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
anpi0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether fe:72:1f:15:fb:03
    media: none
    status: inactive
anpi1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether fe:72:1f:15:fb:04
    media: none
    status: inactive
en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether fe:72:1f:15:fb:e3
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether fe:72:1f:15:fb:e4
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 36:7a:1e:89:38:00
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 36:7a:1e:89:38:04
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 3e:57:dc:61:8f:eb
    media: autoselect
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 1c:57:dc:61:8f:eb
    inet6 fe80::836:4a1e:3ebc:1307%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xb 
    inet 172.16.0.57 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 172.16.3.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
awdl0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 4a:1d:f5:59:b9:5e
    inet6 fe80::481d:f5ff:fe59:b95e%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 36:7a:1e:89:38:00
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 8 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 4a:1d:f5:59:b9:5e
    inet6 fe80::481d:f5ff:fe59:b95e%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xe 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::6919:30d8:e2a5:12e8%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::9724:d631:3a50:ba8f%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x10 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::83a:55f9:d2b0:71cc%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x11 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1000
    inet6 fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun4: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::21ef:39c9:b288:3f35%utun4 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x13 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun5: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::615b:b29c:bc3b:31a8%utun5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x14 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 1e:57:dc:16:13:64
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vmenet2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 25 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: vmenet0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 21 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmenet2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 92:e8:34:64:7a:5f
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmenet0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:6a:67:4c:2a:bd
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmenet1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 62:b8:4d:e2:94:1d
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge101: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 1e:57:dc:16:13:65
    inet 10.37.129.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.37.129.255
    inet6 fe80::1c57:dcff:fe16:1365%bridge101 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x18 
    inet6 fdb2:2c26:f4e4:1::1 prefixlen 64 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vmenet1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 23 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

I have a website that opens at
http://localhost:8888/site

What settings do I need to make to access this site from windows 11, which is located on a parallels virtual machine?

```
C:\Windows\System32>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdb2:2c26:f4e4:0:e34b:1f78:8b60:fd33
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fdb2:2c26:f4e4:0:89ea:3187:eae6:fd2f
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ffa2:df5e:ccdf:4335%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.55.4
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.55.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

I found many instructions on how to set up but none of them helped

I receive the list only at this address
http://172.16.0.57:8888/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjYia.png)

if I enter http://172.16.0.57:8888/pablo-new I get a redirect to http://localhost:8888/pablo-new/
in error
This site can’t be reached